# How to check the value is postive or negative and insert a new value in a column of a data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working with pandas and python and I have a task where, I need to check

```
        GDP         diff    sign
Quarter             
1999q4  12323.3     NaN     None
2000q1  12359.1     35.8    None
2000q2  12592.5     233.4   None
2000q3  12607.7     15.2    None
2000q4  12679.3     71.6    None
```

Let the above dataframe be df and when I do

```
if df.iloc[2]['diff'] > 0:
    df.iloc[2]['sign'] = "Positive"
```

The value is not getting updated on the dataframe. Is there something where I'm doing wrong. Its a direct assignment like how we do df['something'] = 'some value' and by doing this it will insert than value into df under that column. But when i do the above where i need to determine positive or negative, it is still showing as None when I do

```
df.iloc[2]['sign']
```

I tried using apply with lambdas, but couldn't get what I wanted.

Some help would be appreciated
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) first with filtering `NaN` values by [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) and then by condition `df['diff'] > 0`:

```
df.sign = np.where(df['diff'].isnull(), np.nan,
          np.where(df['diff'] > 0,   'Positive', 'Negative'))
print (df)
  Quarter      GDP   diff      sign
0  1999q4  12323.3    NaN       NaN
1  2000q1  12359.1   35.8  Positive
2  2000q2  12592.5  233.4  Positive
3  2000q3  12607.7   15.2  Positive
4  2000q4  12679.3  -71.6  Negative
```

because if use only `df['diff'] > 0` get `Negative` for `NaN` values:

```
df.sign = np.where(df['diff'] > 0, 'Positive', 'Negative')
print (df)
  Quarter      GDP   diff      sign
0  1999q4  12323.3    NaN  Negative
1  2000q1  12359.1   35.8  Positive
2  2000q2  12592.5  233.4  Positive
3  2000q3  12607.7   15.2  Positive
4  2000q4  12679.3  -71.6  Negative
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a categorical column

```
d = df['diff']
sign = np.where(d < 0, 'Negative',
                np.where(d == 0, 'UnChanged',
                         np.where(d > 0, 'Positive', np.nan)))

df['sign'] = pd.Categorical(sign,
                            categories=['Negative', 'UnChanged', 'Positive'],
                            ordered=True)

df
```

[image]